# How to compare 2 dictionary values in Python and make pairs with common ones by keys?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary

I have 2 columns: one is the Pandas DateTime [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOdln.png) (`data["start"]`) and the second is [the tags,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbjlG.png) `data["parallels"]` for example. So i'm going to create a dictionary, like this:

```py
a = []
pl = []
pl1 = []
for i in list(data.index):
    a.append(data["parallels"][i].astype(str))
    if a[i] != 'nan':
        pl1.append(i)
        pl.append(a[i])
    if i > list(data.index)[i]: break
parl1 = dict(zip(pl1,pl))
```

So, the output dictionary is: `{3: '1.0', 5: '1.0'}`
How can i check this dictionary if the values is equal (in the example both are) and after checking write down keys. The output keys i'm going to use as index by making equal column `data["start")[5] == data["start][3]`

I wonder how to do it automatically, if there are `{2: '2.0', 3: '1.0', 4: '2.0', 5: '1.0'}` dict for example.

Comment: your question is not clear.  can you explain your objective as to why are you creating a dictionary from a dataframe?

Comment: because i want to create a method, which are going to making parallel tasks with equal start time, and this values i have in DataFrame

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "make pairs with common ones by keys". Please show an example input and the exact desired corresponding output.

Comment: It seems like you are describing an "inner join" but its a bit difficult to follow your description

Comment: if the values in dictionary are equal, that means the keys is good to go making equal the start time in Dataframe

Comment: so you want rows that have same "start" and "parallels" values?

Comment: if the row 3 and 5 have same "parallels" value, like '1.0' in the example, the must return same "start" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the dictionary so that keys can be grouped together

```py
v = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    v.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

print(v)

import pandas as pd

print(pd.DataFrame({'val': list(v.keys()), 'equal_keys': list(v.values())}))
```

```
{'2.0': {2, 4}, '1.0': {3, 5}}
   val equal_keys
0  2.0     {2, 4}
1  1.0     {3, 5}
```

Other than this, maybe you want to use [pandas groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and aggregate all indices

```
# just an example did not check for errors
df.groupby('parallel').index.agg(list)
```

Comment: thats seems to be the answer! but how can use this new grouped values to make equal row 2 and 4, 3 and 5 in Dataframe?

Comment: You can convert dictiooanry into dataframe. But I recommend trying pandas groupyby